# Best practice to organize model code in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In  rails model we can write many things in single file. (Sample Model)

Sample Model:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Database Assosication
  has_many :post
  belongs_to :user

  # Filter
  before_save :check_full_name

  # Validation
  validates_presence_of :name

  # Scope
  scope :is_paid, -> { where(:status => 'paid') }

  # Constents
  STATUS = {
      :paid => 'paid',
      :pending => 'pending',
      :failed => 'failed'
  }

  # Methods
  def get_name
    # sample code goes here
  end

end
```

In model we use database association, filter, validation, scope, functions.

But what is the best way to organize my model.

I mean what should go first association ? or validation or scope?

Comment: I didn't mean the order! I mean organize.

Comment: see this link: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#models

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is any best practice guideline for this. I will just share my experience.

What I do is:

1. Put all the `constants` in the top.
2. Then, put the `filters` and `validators`
3. Then, comes all the `associations`
4. Next, comes all the `scopes`
5. And after that, all the `methods`

Also, while putting them, we keep them in alphabetical order of their names.

We follow this structure in our codebase and it works well for us. But, really it's a personal/team choice of organizing things in your model.